# How to wireup JS event handler through JS code

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have an HTML element like so:

```
<span id="myspan" ondblclick="edit(this)">Text to be edited</span>
```

How can I bind the same kind of handler -> edit(this)

to the `ondblclick` event through JavaScript? I want something like whats below:

```
function someMethod(){
   var span = document.getElementById("myspan");

   span.ondblclick = edit(span); // This line doesn't work...

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because you are assigning the result of that function to the dbclick handler. Try this instead;

```
span.ondblclick = function() {
    edit(span); 
};
```

Or you can do

```
span.ondblclick = edit;
```

but you need to change your edit function

```
function edit(event) {
    var span = event.target;
    // do your stuff
}
```

That way you target the clicked element.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. I went with the 1st one. I tried the 2nd one but the thing is i need to pass the 'span' as a parameter. can't use the 3rd option since i can't change the edit function. thanks alot:)